# Get the value of: e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have this element in the DOM, which I can read by using this:

```
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1]
```

It renders as this (in the console):

```
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1]
<td>​
"
                                1
                                "
<input length=​"9" data-val=​"true" data-val-number=​"The field TarriffID must be a number." data-val-required=​"The TarriffID field is required." id=​"TarriffID" name=​"TarriffID" type=​"hidden" value=​"44">​
</td>​
```

This is the Markup for it:

```
<tbody id="TarriffsGrid">
                @if (Model.ContractTarriffsList.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var tarriff in Model.ContractTarriffsList)
                    {
                        var count = 1;

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @(count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                                @Html.Hidden("TarriffID", tarriff.TarriffID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "TarriffID")
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @(Math.Round(tarriff.ExcessValue, 2))
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @(Math.Round(tarriff.Rate, 2))
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="radioInput" id="radioInput" class="tarriffRadioButton" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        count++;
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
```

I would like to get the value of (44), but this is not happening with any of the following variations:

```
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1].val();
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1].val;
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1].value;
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1].value();
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1].text;
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1].innerText;
```

...etc.

What could possibly be the solution here please?

Comment: `childNodes[1]` returns the `<td>` element, try going one level deeper to get the `<input>` element and then get the `.value`.

Comment: @Lugia1011101 Thanks, you're right; thats what I've just done below if you have a look it works..

Comment: Warning: IDs need to be unique! Don't use them within a `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this:

```
var tarriffID = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1].firstChild.value;
```

Many thanks.

**Edit**

It was actually this (one step deeper):

```
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].value;
```